# C++ Using interfaces or not?

Tags: c++, api, oop, c++11

I'm programming a library and I'm defining an interface for each class by making it's functions and destructor pure virtual. Now, over the time, I've experienced many disadvantages of this design (- just to name some of them: no static methods possible, a lot of virtual inheritence, and, of course, virtual functions are extremly slow.)
The only advantage I see in interfaces is to provide the user with a simple interface and hide the complex details behind them.
But considering all the disadvantages, I don't see why even big, known libraries are using interfaces. (f.e. Ogre 3D, Irrlicht and many other 3D libraries, where performance is the most important thing.)
My question is:
Is there a really convincing point which I'm missing why to use interfaces? Why do others do that? What is more common - using interfaces or
not using them?
Also, when using interfaces - is it valid to make some sort of "hybrid" design? Where classes relying on performance are implemented directly on the interface layer to avoid virtual function calls, and all other classes are implemented as usual? Or is this a bad design?

Comment: Not sure I'd call virtual functions "extremely slow", but it's true if you're in a tight loop calling a short inline-able function, the vtable lookup indirection can be significant.

Comment: While virtual functions *may* be slower to call than non-virtual functions, I wouldn't to so far as to say they are "extremely slow". If it is, then either your compiler contains bugs or is bad at optimizations, or your design needs a look over, because if you want to use inheritance in C++ it's almost impossible to avoid virtual functions.

Comment: How can you have a library with only interfaces? How do you create your objects? Factory methods? Then they can't be virtual.

Comment: Interfaces are useful for abstracting away implementation details (ex.  MS COM) but it's still messy.  The vtable order has to be defined.  This is one reason APIs tend to be more C-ish than C++.

Comment: I don't think hiding implementation details is a good reason to use "interfaces" (abstract base classes). That's what member visibility is for (public/protected/private). Unless you need to hide the types of some data members from the outside world (as in: you don't want to include internal headers); then it can be an alternative to PIMPL. Otherwise it is only useful if you want polymorphism (for multiple implementations, possibly mock implementations for unit testing).

Comment: maybe you should reconsider why you need static methods in an interface. interfaces are not intended to be a magic bullet, they only solve some distinct design problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Your questions

> Why use interfaces?

"Interfaces" isn't a well defined term in C++: some people consider any base class with virtual methods to be an interface, while others expect there to be no data members, or no public data members, or no private data members; a few people might say *all* members must be virtual, and others that they must be pure virtual.

There are pros and cons to each design decision:

- base classes with virtual functions are C++'s mechanism for runtime polymorphism, which is a great reason to use them
- keeping public data out of the base class preserves freedom to calculate the data on the fly
- keeping private data out of the base class avoids having to change it therein when only the implementation changes; such changes force a client recompilation rather than a re-link (being able to just relink is especially useful when the implementation's in a shared object / library that's dynamically linked, as only an updated library need be distributed)
- virtual dispatch makes it easy to implement state machines (changing the implementatino at run-time), as well as switching in mock implementations for testing

> What is more common - using interfaces or not using them?

That's hugely dependent on the type of application, whether the data inputs or state naturally benefit from runtime polymorphism, and the design decisions made by the programmers' involved.  C++ is used for such wildly divergent purposes that no general statement's meaningful.

> Also, when using interfaces - is it valid to make some sort of "hybrid" design?

Yes - some "hybrid" approaches are listed under "mitigation" below.

### Discussion of your remarks

> "virtual functions are extremly slow"

Actual virtual dispatch is necessarily out-of-line, so can be about an order of magnitude worse than an inline call if doing something very simple (e.g. getter/setter for `int` member), but see mitigation below.  (Often the optimiser can avoid virtual dispatch if the dynamic type of the variable involved is known at compile time).

> "no static methods possible"

Each class can have static methods - there's just no way to invoke them polymorphically, but what would it even mean to do so?  You must have some way to know the dynamic/runtime type as that's the basis for selecting which function to call....

### Mitigation

There are a LOT of options for tuning performance - what you should often becomes obvious when you very carefully consider your actual performance problem.  The following's a random smattering to give a taste of what's possible and occasionally useful....

#### Mitigation - granularity of work performed by virtual functions

Try to do as much work as possible per virtual function call.  For example, a `set_pixel` function taking a single pixel would normally be bad interface design.  A `set_pixels` function that can take an arbitrarily long list would be much better, but there're many other alternatives such as providing some kind of virtual drawing surface that the client code can work on without runtime polymorphic dispatch, then pass back the entire surface in one virtual function call.

#### Mitigation - handover to static-polymorphic code

You can manually orchestrate targeted (per performance profiling results) handover from run-time to compile-time polymorphism (albeit at the cost of manually maintaining a centralised handover routine.

Example

Assume a base class `B` with `virtual void f();`, and two derived `D1`, `D2`.

First, some polyrmophic algorithmic code that explicitly neuters virtual dispatch:

```
template <typename T>
struct Algo
{
    void operator()(T& t)
    {
        .. do lots of stuff...
        t.T::f();  // each t member access explicitly dispatched statically
        ...lots more...
    }
};
```

Then, some code to dispatch to a static-type-specific instantiation of a specified algorithm based on dynamic type:

```
template <template <typename> class F>
void runtime_to_compiletime(B& b) {
    if (D1* p = dynamic_cast<D1*>(&b))
        F<D1>()(*p);
    else if (D2* p = dynamic_cast<D2*>(&b))
        F<D2>()(*p);
}
```

Usage:

```
D1 d1;
D2 d2;
runtime_to_compiletime<Algo>(d1);
runtime_to_compiletime<Algo>(d2);
```

#### Mitigation - orchestrate your own type information

If dynamic_cast is too slow in your implementation, you can get lightning fast switching on dynamic type - at the considerable cost of having to maintain it - as follows:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() : type_(0) { }
    int get_type() const { return type_; }
  protected:
    Base(int type) : type_(type) { }

    int type_;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived() : Base(1) { }
};
```

Then fast switching is trivial:

```
void f(Base* p)
{
    switch (p->get_type())
    {
      ... handle using static type in here ...
    }
}
```

#### Mitigation - data in "interfaces"

Instead of `virtual int f() const;` to expose an `int` data member that only a few derived classes need to calculate on the fly, consider:

```
class Base
{
   public:
     Base() : virtual_f_(false) { }
     int f() const { return virtual_f_ ? virtual_f() : f_; }
   private:
     int f_;
     bool virtual_f_;
     virtual int f() const { }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using interfaces with only pure virtual functions and no private and public data. My approach would be to simply implement the methods some classes directly in the header of the interface. If i understood your answer correctly, this should be no bad design, right?

Comment: @user3067395 "simply implement the methods some classes directly in the header" - that's a little jumbled.  So, you've got all-pure-virtual functions, and you're thinking of making some of their methods/functions "directly in the header"... which means they'll have to be nominally inline (any function defined directly in the class will be implicitly inline), whether or not they remain virtual or even pure virtual (pure virtual functions can have an implementation - vaguely useful if the derived class wants to call it explicitly).  Are you planning to make some non-virtual too?

Comment: Anyway, personally - I don't use classes of pure-virtual functions much, and only make things virtual when there's a likely need.  I tend to put functions and data in to less-derived classes if it seems likely the uses of that class, or most-all derived classes, will want to use it.  Another thing to be aware of though is that the thresholds for preferring pimpl and interfaces for implementation hiding vary vastly: for example, a commercial or widely successful 3D graphics library will want to keep it's API and headers more stable than a library used by a single application.

Comment: I'm sorry - I have expressed myself poorly. I have some classes containing only pure virtual functions, which must be implemented. The other classes are containing no pure virtual functions but are implemented directly - they are not abstract and the user doesn't need a factory to instantiate them (that's what I meant by "hybrid" design). Does this break a good design?

Comment: @user3067395 Have to designing for needs: how you distribute your updated code for use by client code (whether they must recompile or just relink - potentially dynamically), and whether there's value in having a central factory able to tweak the dynamic type of the objects (to substitute custom behaviours, testing, logging, profiling etc.).  Against those benefits, there's the convenience and performance of using stack-based variables rather than smart pointers and heap, and the inlining, dead code elimination, etc. that comes with the compiler sometimes knowing the static type.

Comment: So... you're designing a library.  Will you be the main user, or do you expect a few from your team at work, dozens across your company, folks in a client company, or hundreds/thousands across the 'net?  How will you distribute it?  What does it do?  Do you expect applications using it to accept updates in the form of a new shared library, static library, or source code they'll need to recompile with?

Answer (score 5):

Interfaces are just one of the many mechanisms C++ provides to get reusability and extendibility.

**Reuse**.

If class `A` has a pointer to concrete class `B`, you cannot resuse class `A` withouth `B`.

Solution: you introduce an interface `I` implemented by `B`, and `A` has a pointer to `I`. In this way, you can reuse class `A` in your software (or in other applications) withouth `B` (please note that you bring `I` together with `A` so you need to implement it someway)

**Extendibility**.

If a class `A` has a pointer to concrete class `B`, class `A` is bounded to use the "algorithms" provided by `B`. In future, if you need to use different "algorithms", you are forced to modify `A` source code.

Solution: if `A` has a pointer to an interface `I`, you are free to change `I` implementation (eg. you can substitute `B` with `C`, both implementing `I`) withouth modifying `A` source code.

(By the way: mock implementations for testing are included in the extendibility case).

Let's recap:

- you don't need to define an interface for each class of your software: you only need to put an interface when you need a hot spot for extendibility or reusability (yes: sadly this require you to **think** about your design instead of adopt blindly a rule...).
- C++ offers many techniques to get the same results: instead of interfaces you can use templates or delegates (see `std::function`, `boost::signal` and so on).
- the advantage you see in interfaces ("to provide the user with a simple interface and hide the complex details behind them") is best obtained by means of encapsulation. You don't need interface classes to get information hiding. It's enough that your classes don't export details in the public section.

Comment: Short and clear answer! So basically what you say is, that, for all classes which implementation I may change in the future I should define an interface, and for all classes that I'm sure will not change over time should be defined directly?

Comment: @user3067395 short answer: yes. Long answer: C++ has also other mechanisms to reach the same result (e.g. templates, delegates): you're not forced to always use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use next approach: when you have multiply implementations of same interface and implementation selection should be performed at runtime (maybe those interface and implementation wrap some kind of "strategy" etc.) then you should use "interface-implementation" approach (with factory creation, etc.), when it's some kind of utility functionality - than you should avoid "interface-implementation" approach. You also should not forget about correct objects creation/destruction calls between libraries and main code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using non intrusive polymorphism http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/value-semantics-and-concepts-based-polymorphism-sean-parent can help with problems of multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance by truly separating interface from implementation. This should eliminate the need for virtual inheritance. In my personal opinion virtual inheritance is a sign of bad/old design.

Also if you are using polymorphism in order to achieve the open closed principal then static polymorphism via CRTP can be much faster.

```
class Base { 
    virtual void foo(){
    //default foo which the suer can override
    }
    void bar(){
        foo();
    } 
}
class UserObject : public Base{
    void foo() override{
    //I needed to change default foo, 
    //this probably cannot be inlined unless the compiler is really 
    //good at devirtialization
    }
}
```

becomes

```
template<typename T_Derived>
class Base {
    virtual void foo(){
    //default foo which the suer can override
    }
    void bar(){
        static_cast<T_Derived*>(this)->foo();
    } 
}
class UserObject : public Base<UserObject>{
    void foo() {
    //I needed to change default foo, ths can be inlined no problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One advantage with interfaces is that enables you to write unit tests. When writing a component that uses an interface, you can implement a simple fake version of the interface. The fake version can be given to the component to use during unit tests. This means unit tests will be fast as they don't really execute the library operation. Your fake implementation of the interface can be coded to return values and data to your component to cause it to execute certain code paths and the fake implementation can check that the component made expected calls to the interface.

This convinces me! Obviously, not all libraries are the same. Writing a fake version of a 3D graphics library might not always be useful as you really need to use your own eyes to see the image is correct as a unit test might be tricky to code to check the output is correct here. But, for many other applications unit tests are worth the extra work because they give you confidence to make changes to the code base and be sure it still works as behaves, and help ensure quality.